# как список с вложеными списками переделать в строку

Tags: python, list

у меня есть список:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

как мне сделать, что бы на выводе было

`1 2 3 4`

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
print(*sum(a, []))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
' '.join([ ' '.join(map(str, p)) for p in a ])
```

Comment: в этом случае квадратные скобки не нужны

Comment: @Danis я знаю, оставил для наглядности

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = ""
a = [[1, 2],[3, 4]]
for i in a:
    for b in i:
        s+=str(b)
print(s)
```

Comment: в этом случае join не нужен

Comment: @eri Кстати да.. изначально другой код был перекопировал лишнее))